# Prince of Persia Sands of Time problem

Tags: pc, technical-issues, prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time

The latest Prince of Persia games run, but Sands of Time wont work and shows the video card compatibility problem on my PC .What should i do? Games released after and before sands of time runs fine on my pc

My system specification are:

- 2.0 GHz dual core processor
- 1 GB ram
- 256 MB video g31/g33 card

Comment: I think it will help if you provide more details about the exact nature of the error.

Comment: Perhaps add a screenshot to show us what the error is

Comment: I cant arrange screnshot but it says video card not compatible for this game

Comment: that's an integrated video card from intel. Those are good for office work, not gaming.

Comment: @dierre: I know But as i told i can play other high graphics game

Comment: I know that but those kind of video card, even with that amount of RAM, could be not compatible with some game for lack of some techology. E.g. with my old laptop I could have played football manager (it has 3d matches) but not soldat :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game runs perfectly on Intel processor PCs using [3d analyzer](http://www.tommti-systems.com/main-Dateien/files.html).
Do the following instructions and get rid of it.

1. Open 3d Analyser.
2. Select POP in 3d analyzer.
3. Then under 'Hardware Limits(cap bits)' section select all options.
4. Now under 'Pixel and vertex shader' section select:
   force max. pixel shader 1.4
   skip pixel shader version 2.0
   force low precision pixel shader
5. Use graphic card Vender ID 4098 and Device ID 20040.
6. Now press 'RUN' tab in 3d analyzer.
7. Start game not on safe mode.
8. In game option set fog off.

Now your game will run perfectly on PC but remember that you should choose `pop.exe` in 3d Analyzer not `PrinceOfPersia.exe`.

Comment: also see [here](http://www.theprohack.com/2009/03/using-3d-analyzer-to-play-games-without.html) - it specifically mentions sands
 of time as working

Comment: Thanks angle you have helped me a lot .I have not heard about 3d analyser until you told me and now it works miracles.I have successfully started 4 games with it which were not even launching before like resident evil 4 ,blood money far cry 2 etc.Thanks a lot

Comment: @angle :And these games also works very fine with good graphics.I think 3d analyser only helps to enable hardware tnl which was the only problem with my card.But i am sorry to tell but i have not been able to play sands of time until now .plz help as i love that game